# Fire and forget in flask application

Tags: python-3.x, flask

From my flask application, I am triggering a Jenkins job and after triggering Jenkins I am sending notification mail. I have already implemented this feature.
I want to call a method as soon as i have triggered Jenkins, this method will wait for job completion and check status and send completion email.

I have the code to check Jenkins job status and send mail.

Only problem is how to call this method when Jenkins job is triggered.